# jQuery set DropDownList enabled

Tags: jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have two DropDownList

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" Width="173px" 
                                CssClass="ddl" >
                            </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server" Width="173px" 
                                CssClass="ddl" Enabled="False">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
```

I want when the first one will be  ddl1.selectedindex = 3 to enable the second one ddl2

Comment: Use OnSelectedIndexChanged for ddl1

Comment: OnSelectedIndexChanged is only needed if you want to populate the values of ddl2 on the fly, it causes a postback to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the .change event to check the selected value.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m8dX3/

javascript:

```
$('#ddl1').change(function(){
    var ddl1=$(this);
    var ddl2=$('#ddl2');
    if (ddl1.val()==3) { ddl2.removeAttr('disabled'); }
    else { ddl2.attr('disabled','disabled').val(0); }
});
```

and make sure you use the correct ClientID of the dropdownlists (`$('#<%=ddl1.ClientID%>')`) or use a classname.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if($('[id$="ddl1"]').val() == 3) {
   $('#ddl2').attr("disabled") = "disabled";
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want `$('#ddl2').attr("disabled") = "disabled";`?  The values for disabled are either "disabled" or "".

Comment: No problem, I have made that same mistake =)

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide the non-jquery inline approach:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" Width="173px" 
     CssClass="ddl" onchange="if (this.selectedIndex=3) {document.getElementById('ddl2').disabled=false;}">
                            </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server" Width="173px" 
                                CssClass="ddl" Enabled="False">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
```